# HttpContext is null in derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, controller

I am getting `HttpContext` `null` sometime in the derived class. I am currently inheriting `BaseController` into `ActionLogsController`.

Just look at my code:

BaseController:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

ActionLogsController:

```
public class ActionLogsController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult AddActionLog(ActionLogModel model)
    {
        var name = user.name;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? It gives `null` sometime. Is it just a crash or I need to do any change in my code?

Comment: When asking, please always include the language you are working with - also when it might be obvious by the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

`Controller` already has a `User` property.

Alright, you try create a *new* one, but there is not need to directly couple to `HttpContext` there.

Cast the base property to your custom principle.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {
    protected virtual new CustomPrincipal User {
        get { return base.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

It gets the user from the same place.

[Controller.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs#L154)

```
public IPrincipal User
{
    get { return HttpContext == null ? null : HttpContext.User; }
}
```

The risk with doing what you are doing is that you need to make sure that principle is of the matching type (in this case your custom principle), otherwise the cast will cause the property to always return *null*.

And that is because if the current request's user is not authenticated you may get a principle for an anonymous user, which, since it is not your `CustomPrincipal` will result in *null* being returned when `User` is called.